# Shrink volume - Error: parameter incorrect - Window 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I've just buy a new HP laptop (PC) with 256Gb SSD storage running Window 10, and I'm trying to split my C drive into 2 partitions.  
In the `Computer Management` window under `Storage` >> `Disk Management` I right click the C drive and click `Shrink Volume`, and get the Error `parameter incorrect`

My disk is split into: 
Disk #1 260MB - Healthy (EFI) 
Disk #2 224GB - Windows (C Drive) 
Disk #3 980MB - Healthy (Recovery) 
Disk #4 12GB  - Recover (D Drive)

[image]

I believe I get the error due to the fact that the Disk #3 - Healthy (Recover) Disk is located after the C drive - This is only a theory.

How can I Shrink my C drive???

Comment: use 3rd party tools, the inbox tool of windows is very limited

Comment: Very odd --- Why do you have the recovery partition mapped to any drive letter (D:)?  Usually, it shouldn't be--mine isn't.  Also, why TWO drive D:s for the same partition?   Conjecture on my part, but perhaps the portion of the C: partition it needs to reduce, is actually in-use.  If so, maybe defrag and it will move any data written there, to an "inner track".  "Mini-Tool" may do this data moving for you, before it reduces it.  Confirm both of these methods, elsewhere though. (Yes, I know--SSD's don't have tracks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I find a solution - using a slag-hammer - formatting this machine. I know that this solution is quite extreme but it's OK for me since this is a new machine without any user data.

After talking with an expert in this field, he explains to me that indeed as I thought - I can't shrink C drive, because the shrinking process takes the end of the drive and uses this memory for the new drive. However, my C drive had a recovery partition (the 980MB) at the end of it - therefore Windows couldn't shrink this drive since the end of the drive is occupied.

So my solution was formatting Window (no licenses or activation code was needed since Windows 10 uses the old activation key when reformatting Windows)

And in the formatting process, I deleted the Healthy and Recover (D drive) since it's really don't needed (I can simply install a clean version of Windows, instead of restoring to manufacture defaults - this way I got additional 12GB of space)

For more w on how to install a clean version of Window on your old ACTIVATED version of Windows see: https://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/

Comment: I would advise against using "slag-hammers" on computer equipment. Your DIY shop should have a sledge hammer however.

Answer (score 7):

Solution:
Run cmd and type: diskpart

DISKPART> list volume
(write down or remember the ### of the Volume you needed to extend or size in DISK Management does Not match)

DISKPART>select volume <###>

DISKPART>extend filesystem

(Now the filesystem size should match/be in tune with the new partition size) and you should Not get the 'parameter incorrect' error.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use something like [EaseUS Partition Master FREE](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html) to resize your partitions. It works way better, in my experience, than Windows' own tool, and let's you drag the sizer.